socket.io doesn't have a connection
The socket.io's connection doesn't work for some reason and the connection log doesn't appear on the console log. I tried to follow step-by-step of the socket.io's documentation, but still nothing works...
Here's are the files of the codes, you can mainly see to what I mean in the "connection" route of socket's snippet code on the index.js file.
The index.html file conatins  tags that are responsible to receive the inputs from the form.
index.js:
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join } from 'node:path';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});



io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");
    socket.on("chat message", (msg) => {
        console.log("Message: " + msg);
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("User disconnected");
    });
});




app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>



    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>  
       const socket = io();

       const form = document.getElementById("form");
       const input = document.getElementById("input");

       form.addEventListener((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(input.value){
          socket.emit("emit message", input.value);
          input.value = "";
        }
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

package.json:
{
  "name": "chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5"
  }
}


You are creating two separate web server instances, binding express to one of them and socket.io to the other and only starting the express server.  So, the socket.io server is never started and should actually be using the same server as express (since it's on the same port).
You can fix it by changing this:
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});

to this:
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});

That way, you're attaching socket.io to the same server instance that you also bound express to and it's the one that you're calling .listen() on.  That allows them both to use your one running server instance on the same port.

To help you understand:
See code for app.listen() here.
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};

You can clearly see it is creating a separate server instance and starting it and this is not the instance that you put socket.io on.
See doc for app.listen() here.

The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object and (for HTTP)
is a convenience method for the following:

